# Call function of kernel module from another kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am new to kernel driver development. So I am just stuck in that. How can I call the function of the kernel module from another kernel module? These are both my `.c` files.

**module1.c:**

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

int multiplication(int a, int b)
{
    int ans=0;
    ans = a * b;
    printk(KERN_INFO"Returns the Multiplication to Module2!: %d\n", ans);
    return ans;
}
```

**module2.c:**

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>

void calling()
{
    int a=2,b=3;
    int ans=0;
    ans = multiplication(a,b) // function of module1.c.
    printk(KERN_INFO"Multiplication recieved from Module1!: %d\n", ans);
}
```

I want to call the `multiplication` function in `module2.c` from `module1.c`. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

To call a function defined in another kernel module you would have to export that function.

[EXPORT_SYMBOL](https://lkw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/doc/04_exporting_symbols.html)

> EXPORT_SYMBOL() helps you provide APIs to other modules/code.

> The functions which you EXPORT are available to the other modules/code.

Start with using the `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` function in `module1.c` after defining the function:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(multiplication);
```

Then you can declare the function as an external symbol using the `extern` keyword in `module2.c`:

```
extern int multiplcation(int, int);
```

Once you have built the modules, insert the module that is exporting the symbol and then insert the module that is importing the symbol. In this case, you would insert `module1.ko` and then `module2.ko`

There are some examples available at the "EXPORT_SYMBOL" hyperlink above

Comment: This may not work. Because my question is that, both modules can be inserted into the kernel independently. If I first insert the module2.ko it may not get loaded into the kernel.

Comment: Yeah, if you insert module2.ko first it will not be inserted within the kernel since the multiplication symbol would not be defined. You would get an `unknown symbol` error. This was not mentioned in your question so I was not aware that you wanted the modules to be loaded independently. I am not sure if what you are asking for is possible since the kernel would require all functions in a module to be defined before insertion.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Yes, it is possible you can use function pointers :)